# Moving a div relative to another div having horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;height: 80px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden;width:550px;" id="div1">
    <div style="width: 1650px; display: block;">
    </div>
</div>

<div style="width: 550px; position: absolute;" id="div2">
</div>
```

I wish to move the `div` with `id="div2"` in relative way in opposite direction to the movement of the scroll bar of the `div` with `id="div1"`.

Using jquery or javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
$('#div1').scroll(function() {
    $('#div2').css('left', $(this).scrollLeft() * -1);
});
```

jsFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/qJF2g/1/).

Comment: Awesome !! works best for me , also 
`$('#div2').css('right', $(this).scrollLeft());` this also works for me.

Answer (score -1):

I guess that what you want.

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;height: 80px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden;width:550px;" id="div1">
    <div style="width: 1650px; display: block;">
    </div>

<div style="width: 550px; position: absolute;" id="div2"></div>

</div>
```